Notepad++ wildcard with "replace"
I am having difficulty using wildcard character (.) to replace text.  It works fine to find the desired text; but instead of retaining the "wildcard" text, it replaces it with .
I want to replace:
releasetime="2024-06-ddT:08:00:00Z"
With:
releasetime="2024-06-ddT:06:59:00Z"
(Note:  dd is a date, so it can be one of several values)
I tried this:
Find:  releasetime=.*08:00:00Z
Replace:  releasetime=.*06:59:00Z
But the end result comes out as
releasetime=.*06:59:00Z"
Also note that I can't just replace 08:00:00 with 06:59:00, because this value is found in conjunction with text other than "releasetime"

Use capture group (parentheses) and backreferencing (backslash notation): releasetime=(.*)08:00:00Z Replace: releasetime=\106:59:00Z
